# zend framework2 How to echo out multiple checkbox separately

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using Zend MultiCheckbox form element

```
   $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox',
        'name' => 'conferenceoption',
        'options' => array(

            'value_options' => array(
                'conference Program' => 'Conference',
                'Evening Program' => 'Evening Programme',
            ),
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => '1' //set selected to '1'
        )
    ));
```

When I echo them out in my view with,

```
echo $this->formMultiCheckbox($form->get('conferenceoption'));
```

Then, I getting something like this,

[image]

But What I would really like to have is,

[image: But What I would really like to have is,]

THanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer sorry for this.......

We can use,

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="conferenceoption[]" value="conference Program">';
echo '<br>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="conferenceoption[]" value="Evening Program">';
```